# How to read .xlsx file contents in flex3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, excel-2007, flex3

I need to know how to read .xlsx file contents in flex3. Does anyone comes across this problem please give some idea to accomplish this task. If any good API please let me know.

I tried to read .xlsx file using the below sample code but its not working, but its working fine for .xls file.

```
// on creation complete
private function onCreate(e:Event):void
{
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("C://test.xlsx");
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(request);
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onURLLoaderComplete); 
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY; 
urlLoader.load(request);
}

// on file load complete
private function onURLLoaderComplete(event:Event):void
{
        loadedFile = event.target.data;
    var excelFile:ExcelFile = new ExcelFile();
    excelFile.loadFromByteArray(loadedFile);
    sheet = excelFile.sheets[0]; 
    Alert.show(sheet.getCell(1,0).value) 
    DataGrid.dataProvider=sheet.values; 
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need cell values, save it as CSV - it is very simple to parse (unlike xlsx.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need to read all 3 Excel type formats such as CSV,xls and xlsx. I can able to read CSV and xls file values but i can't in xlsx. If any idea about xlsx file format thats more useful for me.

Comment: There's no default parser for that from Adobe (for sure). On this page you'll find xlsx spec from MS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd922181%28v=office.12%29.aspx Never heard about readymade parser in AS3, though.